# rxbag human readable timestamp: local or UTC time?

Tags: ros, rxbag, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the human readable timestamp shown in rxbag status bar, at the right of the raw sec.nsec representation, is in local time.

Indeed, in `$(rospack find rxbag)/src/rxbag/bag_helper.py` the `stamp_to_str` function, which performs the conversion to string, uses the Python `time.localtime` method, instead of `time.gmtime` that [converts to UTC time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.gmtime).

Shouldn't it be shown in UTC? Or at least put some `UTC+N` suffix?
With the current implementation, should I expect that time string to change when daylight or timezone in my pc changes?

Maybe this is quite pedantic ---I admit---, or I'm just missing something. Thanks any way in advance for clarifying.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28855/rxbag-human-readable-timestamp:-local-or-utc-time?/) by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on ROS Answers with karma: 834 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-04-25**:
Ticket [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3936).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you'd like this fixed I suggest you open a ticket for it [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket?component=rx&type=enhancement&rx)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1